# Why does the samba server save files larger than 1M, and then execute the sync file twice in a row and lose it on linux ？

Tags: samba

I found that if I saved the file below 1M through samba, and then executed sync twice in succession, the file would be lost, so I was curious about the working principle of samba.

To save data through samba, the client writes to the cache first, and the system periodically executes sync to add the contents of the cache to the write queue, and then the system writes the contents of the write queue to the disk?

Comment: Please explain why you are running this sync command twice and also where is the Ubuntu version info?

Comment: @David The program executes sync() twice consecutively. The kernel verion is 4.1.18.

Comment: You have still not said what version of Ubuntu you are using, I do not recognize that kernel. A kernel is not a version, a version is something like Ubuntu 20.04.1